# Magneto2: Base table or view not found table amasty_conf_group_attr doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, table, amasty

The changes made in products attributes doesn't show on the frontend. The part of the database won't update and shows the following message.
"Base table or view not found table amasty_conf_group_attr doesn't exist"
The status:upgrade won't install the missing table either.

What is the best solution to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed after updating plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following steps?

Step 1 : If Module install partial or some table missing in the database then do the following.

> Remove Module entry from setup_module table.

Step 2 : Execute the setup upgrade below commands for reinstall the module again.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

> Table 'amasty_conf_group_attr' doesn't exist

This error means you do not have a required table in the database. Looks like an extension was not installed properly.

Your setup is facing an issue with the Amasty extension.

Please first disable and remove code of your `Amasty` extension which is not properly installed in your setup.

Run below commands.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this helps.